# Run specific sql for each DB only when state_desc is ONLINE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to create a script that would run across all the DB's and delete rows from a specific table older than X months. The scipt is working but to make more stable I would like to put som conditions in it. 
One condition is that it would only run when the DB has state_desc like 'ONLINE' if that fails I would like to log the DB that was not processed.

script:

```
    declare @result table ( servername         sysname
                      , dbname             sysname
                      , rows_deleted numeric(15, 0)
                      )

insert into @result
exec sp_MSforEachDB
'if ''?'' like ''DB_%'' 
begin
 -- delete all rows older then 13 months
Delete
  from ?..TABLE1
 where timestamp < DATEADD(month, -6, CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE));
 -- display result
Select @@ServerName
     , ''?'' as dbname
     , @@rowcount as rows_deleted
end'

select * from @result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would use a cursor over a `sys.databases` query with the desired filter rather than use the undocumented `sp_MSforeachdb` stored procedure.

You can add `DATABASEPROPERTYEX` criteria to your existing `IF` statement for conditional execution:

```
DECLARE @result TABLE (
      servername         sysname
    , dbname             sysname
    , rows_deleted numeric(15, 0)
);

INSERT INTO @result
EXEC sp_MSforEachDB
'
if ''?'' like ''DB_%'' AND DATABASEPROPERTYEX(N''?'',''STATUS'') = ''ONLINE'' AND DATABASEPROPERTYEX(N''?'',''Updateability'') = ''READ_WRITE''
BEGIN
 -- delete all rows older then 13 months
DELETE
  FROM [?]..TABLE1
 WHERE timestamp < DATEADD(month, -6, CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE));
 -- display result
SELECT @@ServerName
     , ''?'' as dbname
     , @@rowcount as rows_deleted
end
';
SELECT *
FROM @result;
```

Comment: any reason you used CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE) instead of getdate() here?

Comment: @KevinOlree, I'm not the author of that code but it seems the intent is delete rows older than 6 months based on midnight rather than 6 months plus the current time of day.